# Javascript code to get days remaining to xmas not giving any output

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this code to display the current date and the days remaining to xmas in the input tag inside a table. The same code works if not kept inside a form/table (just normal js, document.write) but when i keep it inside the table&form it does not give any output. plz help me correct my mistake.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Question 4</title>

    <script language="javascript">

    document.write("<h1> Question 4 </h1>");    

    myDate = new Date(); 
    xmas = Date.parse("Dec 25, "+myDate.getFullYear()); 
    today = Date.parse(myDate); 

    days=Math.round((xmas-today)/(1000*60*60*24));

    document.getElementById("date").value = myDate;


    if (days==0) {
    document.getElementById("name2").value = "Today is Christmas!"; 
    }
    if (days<0) {
    document.getElementById("name2").value = "<br>Xmas was " + -1*(days) + " days ago."; 
    }
    if (days>0) {
    document.getElementById("name2").value = "<br>There are " + days + " days to Xmas!";
    }

    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <center>
    <form name="form1">
        <table border=2 width=50% cellspacing=5 cellpadding=8 bgcolor=cyan cols=2>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2 align=center>
                    When Is Christmas?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Todays Date:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="date" id="name">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Days to Christmas:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="date2" id="name2">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </center>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `today = Date.parse(myDate); ` is not the best way to make a copy of a date - use `today = new Date(myDate.getTime());`

Comment: Also, declare your variables with `var`

Comment: @Pointy: new Date(oldDate) is simpler (there's no need for getTime(), ever)...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you have a couple of things going on here.

1. You are looking for the value of element with id date, but no element exists. Update  `<input name="date" id="name">` to be `<input name="date" id="date">`
2. Your code is trying to execute before the page has been fully loaded, and therefore the DOM is not ready.  If you move your script section to just before the `</body>`, the page will be ready.

After that, you should be able to drop `new Date()` instead of "hello", and you'll start seeing some progress.

Comment: Any chance you could accept the answer if it worked for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, change

```
<input name="date" id="name">
```

to

```
<input name="date" id="date">
```